# Question regarding $W$ as not hyperarithmetic

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, computability-theory

Consider the indexes of all ordinary programs generating functions from $\mathbb{N}^2$ to $\{0,1\}$. If we let $W$ be the set of exactly of all those indexes $e$ such that $\phi_e$ computes a total function that represents a well-order relation (on $\mathbb{N}$) for a recursive ordinal $\geq \omega$ then I think $W$ is not hyperarithmetic. That's because I have read it multiple times on various points.

Now consider the result that sets generated by an OTM (or, I think, reasonably similar model of ordinal comp.) in less than $\omega_{CK}$ time are equivalent to hyperarithmetic. Hopefully I am not making a mistake here, but it seems(?) that this result could be used to show that $W$ is not hyperarithmetic (given the assumption that $\omega_{CK}$ is admissible).

I seems that there is a relatively easy construction that shows that if $W$ was hyperarithmetic then $\omega_{CK}$ wouldn't be admissible. Hence we can conclude that $W$ is not hyperarithmetic. I have a question here that has been bothering a bit for a while, ever since few years ago that I noticed this point.

**(Q1)** The first concern is of course of "circularity". What I mean is that I have no idea what showing $\omega_{CK}$ as admissible really entails in terms of set theory involved. For example, perhaps(?) showing $\omega_{CK}$ as admissible already necessarily uses $W$ as non-hyperarithmetic as a lemma, which would make the above construction perhaps useful as an aid but void as a result. Since I don't know much in the way of detail here I thought it would be reasonable to ask.

**(Q2)** Secondly also I am wondering about one other point. We can use $<\omega_{CK}$-time sets as hyperarithmetic to also show for example the result mentioned by Andreas Blass here  [Mapping between Notations](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/278045/mapping-between-notations) (see the comments below the answer). In one sentence, somewhat informally, the result is that the "mapping" between any two recursive well-orders must be hyperarithmetic.

Once again I am wondering whether there is any "circularity" in using OTM to show such a result or not? I am thinking not but I think it is better to be ask, since it is still just a guess on my part.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a proof that $\omega_1^{\mathrm{ck}}$ is admissible;
if someone knows where this fact is proved in the literature, please comment.

First note that there is no $\alpha<\omega_1^{\mathrm{ck}}$
which is admissible: otherwise we have a recursive wellorder $<^*$ in $L_\alpha$
which has length $\alpha$,
and this easily contradicts admissibility.

Now toward showing that $\omega_1^{\mathrm{ck}}$ is admissible, the key is first to observe that $\omega_1^{\mathrm{ck}}$ is also the sup of the $\Delta^1_1$ wellorders of $\omega$. For this, use the local/effective version of the Kunen-Martin theorem (Moschovakis, "Descriptive set theory" 2009 Ed, Theorem 2G.2). That is, let $<^*$ be a $\Delta^1_1$ wellorder of $\omega$.
Let $T$ be a recursive tree on $\omega^3$
such that for $m,n<\omega$,
we have $m<^*n$ iff there is $b\in{^\omega}\omega$ with $(m,n,b)\in[T]$ (the set of infinite branches of $T$). Then let $R$ be the tree of attempts to build an infinite descending sequence through $<^*$, together with witnessing branches through $[T]$. That is, $R$ consists of finite sequences
$$(\sigma_0,\sigma_1,\ldots,\sigma_{k-1})$$
where for each $i$,
$$\sigma_i=(m_0,m_1,\ldots,m_{i},b_0,b_1,\ldots,b_{i-1})$$
where $m_j<\omega$ for each $i\leq i$, $b_j:i\to\omega$ for each $j\leq i$, and
$$(m_j,m_{j+1},b_j)\in T$$
for each $j\leq i$,
and if $i<k$ then $\sigma_i$ is ``consistent'' with $\sigma_{i+1}$, meaning that if
$$\sigma_{i+1}=(m_0',m_1',\ldots,m_{i+1}',b_0',b_1',\ldots,b_i')$$,
then $m_j=m_j'$ for each $j\leq i$,
and $b_j=b_j'\upharpoonright i$ for each $j\leq i$. Define an associated relation $S$ on $\omega$ by setting $mSn$
iff either $m\in R$ but $n\notin R$,
or $m,n\in R$ and $m$ is a proper extension of $n$ (so e.g. with $\sigma_i,\sigma_{i+1}$ as before, we have $\sigma_{i+1}S\sigma_i$). Then $S$ is wellfounded because $<^*$ is,
but a straightforward argument shows that $S$ has rank at least that of $<^*$. Noting that the field of $R$ is recursive, we can convert $S$ into a recursive wellorder of $\omega$ of rank at least that of $S$, via the usual Kleene-Brouwer ordering.

Okay, now suppose that $\omega_1^{\mathrm{ck}}$ is not admissible. Then easily enough, we can fix a $\Sigma_1$ formula $\varphi$
such that $L_{\omega_1^{\mathrm{ck}}}\models$"For all $n<\omega$
there is $\beta\in\mathrm{OR}$ such that $\varphi(n,\beta)$", but there is no $\gamma<\omega_1^{\mathrm{ck}}$ such that $L_\gamma$ models the same statement.
We can use this to define a $\Delta^1_1$ wellorder of $\omega$ in ordertype $\omega_1^{\mathrm{ck}}$, a contradiction.
For this, put $$(n,m)<^*(n',m')$$
iff $n,m,n',m'<\omega$ and  $n\leq n'$,
and if $n=n'$
then there is a model $M$ for the language of set theory, such that:

- $M\models$"$V=L$",
- $M$ has wellfounded $\omega$,
- $M\models\varphi(n,\beta)+$"no proper segment of me models $\varphi(n,\beta)$", and
- $\pi^M(m)<\pi^M(m')$,
  where $\pi^M$ is the $M$-definably least bijection $\omega\to\mathrm{OR}\cap M$.

The model $M$ mentioned above is unique up to isomorphism, by Ville's Lemma / the Truncation Lemma. (That is, any such $M$ is wellfounded, and hence $M\cong L_\alpha$ for the least $\alpha$ such that $L_\alpha\models\varphi(n,\beta)$.
For otherwise the wellfounded part of $M$ would be admissible, contradicting the earlier observation.) And it projects to $\omega$, so there is indeed an $M$-definable bijection $\pi:\omega\to\mathrm{OR}\cap M$.

Note that this gives a $\Sigma^1_1$ welorder of $\omega^2$, hence in fact a $\Delta^1_1$ such wellorder,
whose length is $\geq\omega_1^{\mathrm{ck}}$, a contradiction.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Obviously it is a bit too advanced for me. Nevertheless, my first question (Q1) could essentially be summarized as [possibly a naive question since I don't know the underlying details well]: "Is there a way to show $\omega_1^{\mathrm{ck}}$ as admissible without first showing that set $W$ (from OP) is non-hyperarithmetic?" I don't know whether that is the case for the specific argument you mentioned. But in any case you should keep this answer since it would be quite useful in any case.

Comment: Well the proof above doesn't assume that $W$ is non-hyperarithmetic. But the issue is related to what happens in the proof: the way that the wellorder of $\omega^2$ is defined at the end is analogous to what you could do if you assumed that $W$ is hyperarithmetic, and used that to define a computable wellorder which is impossibly long. But anyway, it's not circular.

Comment: (My comment above didn't attempt to directly answer your question in your comment, because I don't really understand that question. I mean, the proof I wrote certainly doesn't have, as its first step, to show that $W$ is non-hyperarithmetic. But even if it did, I could always artificially modify the proof and change that step to something slightly different, say showing that some set $W_2$ is non-hyperarithmetic, which is not literally $W$, but I can use it in a similar fashion. So it's not clear to me what your question really means.)

Comment: I suppose you could interpret my question (Q1) something like this: **"** If we placed your answer first as an argument for $\omega_1^{\mathrm{ck}}$ admissibility followed by the argument that I mentioned before Q1 then (under the assumption what I wrote is correct) would it seem like even a "half reasonable" [possibly even if somewhat roundabout] way to show that $W$ is non-hyperarithmetic? **"** In an ideal case to the answer one could remove the "half" from phrase "half reasonable". But even the latter is a somewhat positive answer to question. It does seem subjective in general though.

Comment: It seems that this is what you were trying to say perhaps? Once we have shown (or assume) the fact that the supremum of hyperarithmetic well-orderings on $\mathbb{N}$ is equal to $\omega_1^{\mathrm{ck}}$ then $W$ being non-hyperarithmetic follows easily from that? Sorry if I misunderstood you. It does seem to me that in that case a meaningful "non-circular" answer to (Q1) wouldn't be possible with any proof of admissibility of $\omega_1^{\mathrm{ck}}$ that uses the fact mentioned at beginning of this comment.

Comment: So, to the extent that I can understand what you were saying, I do agree with you. (it took me some time to understand the point in my previous comment ..... it seems that a construction similar to this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3046078/what-is-a-simple-method-of-combining-an-infinite-or-finite-set-of-well-orders/3046146#3046146 would suffice)

Answer (score 4):

As (maybe?) a classical computability theorist, here's how I think of this:

From $W$ we can obviously construct a copy of $\omega_1^{CK}$, namely $$\sum_{e\in W}\Phi_e$$ where $\Phi_e$ is the relation computed by $e$. So $W$ computes a well-ordering not isomorphic to any computable well-ordering.

Now a separate result by Spector shows that every *hyperarithmetic*, or even $\Sigma^1_1$, well-ordering is isomorphic to a computable well-ordering. The standard proof - which can be found in [Sacks' *Higher recursion theory*](https://projecteuclid.org/ebooks/perspectives-in-logic/Higher-Recursion-Theory/toc/pl/1235422631) or [Ash/Knight's *Computable structures and the hyperarithmetic hierarchy*](https://www.sciencedirect.com/bookseries/studies-in-logic-and-the-foundations-of-mathematics/vol/144/suppl/C) - uses the $\Pi^1_1$-completeness of $W$, but this isn't circular since we don't at this point in the story know that the projective hierarchy doesn't collapse; alternatively, for a more "hands-on" construction see [this old answer of mine](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/267330/reference-request-a-version-of-sigma1-1-bounding-for-structures) (taking the "structure parameter" $\mathfrak{A}$ to be something boring, say $(\mathbb{N};+)$). There are also proofs in [Beckmann/Pohlers (theorem 3.7)](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0168007297000638) and [Pauly (corollary 81)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1501.00386), but I'm not familiar with those enough to comment.

All of the above is done without reference to admissibility at all, and - while there is indeed no circularity to worry about here - this may feel more concrete.

Comment: Yes, you are indeed right. While I don't understand your answer fully, it seems that part of what you are saying is that (please correct if I am wrong) once we show that supremum of hyperarithmetic well-orderings on $\mathbb{N}$ is equal to $\omega_{CK}$ then $W$ being non-hyperarithmetic follows easily from that. I can see why that is true (though using $<\omega_{CK}$-time definition of hyperarithmetic tbh). This is what I was trying to say in comments below the answer by Farmer S. Also, thanks for the references. They are certainly useful.

Comment: @SSequence I'm a bit confused: leaving circularity issues aside, which fact on its own are you worried about? The non-hyperarithmeticity of $W$, or the admissibility of $\omega_1^{CK}$?

Comment: None of these. I mentioned originally in (Q1) that  it is possible to show non-hyperarithmeticity of $W$ using admissibility of $\omega^{CK}_1$. So I was just wondering what showing admissibility (perhaps multiple ways of showing it)  of $\omega^{CK}_1$ actually entailed (read: "required in steps of its proof"). This is why the other answer is quite helpful.

Comment: @SSequence Ah, I see; that wasn't clear to me.  I'll delete this answer if you'd like.

Comment: I don't think you should. There are number of useful references in the answer.